# How to deal with null in an array when iterating

Tags: java, arrays, null

I am dealing with a classical Nim game project. The hurdle for me is to "only" use an array to save player in an object array, which means I will always get `NullPointerException` when testing. And I've searched almost all the information that there is no such a way to handle this problem.

One way to deal with it is to add `if arr[i] != null` for checking `non-null` object when iterating, but then, I need to write it for every method I created. Is there any way to pass only the `non-null` array to be checked?

Here is part of my code `Nimsys`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Nim\n");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.print('$');
        String commandin = in.next();

        if (commandin.equals("addplayer")) {
            String inputName = in.nextLine();
            String[] name = splitName(inputName);
            addPlayer(name);
        }

        if (commandin.equals("removeplayer")) {
            String user = in.nextLine().trim();

            if (user.equals("")) {
                System.out.println("Are you sure you want to remove all players? (y/n) \n");

                commandin = in.next();
                if (commandin.equals("y")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < NimPlayer.getCounter(); i++) {
                        NimPlayer.getPlayer()[i] = null;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Remove all the players");
                }
            }
            if (!user.equals("")) {
                searchAndRemovePlayer(user);
            }
        }
 public static void searchAndRemovePlayer(String user) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NimPlayer.getCounter(); i++) {
        String userName = NimPlayer.getPlayer()[i].getUserName().trim();
        if (userName.equals(user)) {
            NimPlayer.getPlayer()[i] = null;
            System.out.println("Remove successfully!\n");// A test to see if the code runs
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The player does not exist.\n");
}
}
```

And, below is part of my `NimPlayer` class.

```
//username, given name, family name, number of game played, number of games won
public class NimPlayer {
private String userName;
private String familyName;
private String givenName;
private int score;
private int gamePlayed;

private static int counter;
private static final int SIZE = 5;
static NimPlayer[] playerList = new NimPlayer[SIZE]; // set an array here

//define NimPlayer data type
public NimPlayer(String userName, String surName, String givenName) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.familyName = surName;
    this.givenName = givenName;

}
// create new data using NimPlayer data type
public static void createPlayer(String userName, String familyName, String givenName) {
    if (counter<SIZE) {
        playerList[counter++] = new NimPlayer(userName, familyName, givenName);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cannot add more players.");
    }
}
public static int getCounter() {
    return counter;
}
public static NimPlayer [] getPlayer() {
    return playerList;
}

//getters and setters

}
```

Comment: I would suggest the reassigning array by filtering the null values as follows `NimPlayer .getPlayer() = Arrays.stream(NimPlayer.getPlayer()).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray()`

Comment: Very straight forward, but where should I put this statement? As you can see, I have `getplayer()` to return the `playerList` @dkb

Comment: after `if (!user.equals("")) { searchAndRemovePlayer(user);  removeNullPlayers(user); // like this`

Comment: okay, I got the idea. Actually, I have many ` commands` functions to iterate through the array. It means I have to add for every method I've created, right? @dkb

Comment: If you're 'only' supposed to use it to save players, how does the null get in there in the first place? Isn't that the problem you should be solving?

Comment: It is inevitable to face the null value in the array. I have an array to save player data, but if I remove the data, it will be null in the array if I try to iterate through the array, causing `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @dkb your suggestion is GOOD as I found that when removing the object by assigning the `null`, it won't filter the null space automatically if I only put the filter in `getPlayer()` method.

Comment: yes, you can add as many filters as you want in the pipeline and get valid players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as below,

```
public static void searchAndRemovePlayer(String user) {
    NimPlayer[] players = Arrays.stream(NimPlayer.getPlayer())
                                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                .toArray(NimPlayer[]::new);
    for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {  // replaced NimPlayer.getCounter() to avoid Index Out of Bound
        String userName = players[i].getUserName().trim();
        if (userName.equals(user)) {
            players[i] = null;
            System.out.println("Remove successfully!\n");// A test to see if the code runs
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The player does not exist.\n");
}
```

Note that `NimPlayer.getCounter()` is replaced with arr length to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Update:
You can add the logic in `getPlayer()`

```
 public static NimPlayer [] getPlayer() {
    NimPlayer[] nimPlayers = Arrays.stream(playerList)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .toArray(NimPlayer[]::new);
    counter = nimPlayers.length;  //update the counter
    return nimPlayers;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for spending some time working with it. It's clear and sound. But, is there any way to deal with the `getPlayer()` method in the `NimPlayer` class? If it can return the non-null array? @Code_Mode

Comment: You can put logic in `getPlayer()` as well. Just don't forget to update counter.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to be rude, sir. I am quite new to Java. How can I update the counter?  @Code_Mode

Comment: Thank you, sir! It's amazing! But I got weird output, which is `at JavaAssign2.NimPlayer.getPlayer(NimPlayer.java:40)` repeatedly, and the program ends itself. @Code_Mode

Comment: You need to use `Arrays.stream(playerList)`, updated the answer. Earlier, it was calling same method recursively.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. Have a nice day. @Code_Mode

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a non-null array outside the given section of the program. In the sense, use a loop to create a non-null array that you can use throughout both programs and you can probably store that in a method or instance variable.

Comment: I understand that logically, but could you please give an example to illustrate this idea? @Arny